# Extracting a graph from 2 dimension

Tags: r, igraph

Having this data:

```
       keyword1  keyword2  keyword3
  art1    0          1        0
  art2    1          1        0
  art3    0          0        1
```

It is possible to extract a graph using this:

```
    library(igraph)
    df1<-data.frame(keyword1=c(0,1,0),keyword2=c(1,1,0),keyword3=c(0,0,1),row.names=c("art1","art2","art3"))
  df1.mt <- as.matrix(df1)
  df1.adj <- t(df1.mt) %*% df1.mt
    diag(df1.adj) <- 0
    g <- graph.adjacency(df1.adj)
    plot(g)
```

if data have this format:

```
        keyword1  keyword2  keyword3 
  artA      0          1        0 
  artA      1          1        0  
  artB      0          0        1
  artB      1          1        0  
  artC      1          1        0
```

How is it possible to extract the graph?

Comment: It might help if you would explain what graph you are trying to extract. It might be obvious to you, but please explain for the benefit of someone who doesn't already know what you are trying to do. What should the output be for the table you give at the bottom?

Comment: @JohnColeman with this data I try to find communities based on the first column (artA, artB..) based on the other columns keyword1, keyword2 etc. Column act is just used as an id column and this could not included in the dataset for the graph

Comment: It would help if you edit your question to give the specific output for that example. What are the nodes? What are the edges? Saying that is is "based on other columns ... etc." is still on the vague side.

Comment: @JohnColeman nodes are the keywordn columns and edges are the rows/group of first column (artA, artB, artC) and I try find a way to see which keywordn exist more in every artA,artB, artC group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function which takes a binary matrix and creates an adjacency matrix for the columns, where two columns are said to be adjacent if for some row, both of the entries in those columns are 1's:

```
adj.matrix <- function(B){
  n <- ncol(B)
  g <- expand.grid(1:n,1:n)
  adj <- apply(g,MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(v){max(pmin(B[,v[1]],B[,v[2]]))})
  dim(adj) <- c(n,n)
  diag(adj) <- 0
  colnames(adj) <- colnames(B)
  row.names(adj) <- colnames(B)
  graph.adjacency(adj)
}
```

To test it:

```
B <- rbind(c(1,1,0,0,0),
          c(0,0,1,1,0),
          c(0,0,0,1,1),
          c(0,0,1,0,1))
colnames(B) <- c("A","B","C","D","E")

g <- adj.matrix(B)
plot(g)
```

Resulting graph:

[image]

I am not 100% sure what you intend to do with the second format. It looks like your second format is a dataframe of the following form:

```
df <- data.frame(names=c("artA","artA","artB","artB","artC"),keyword1=c(0,1,0,1,1),keyword2=c(1,1,0,1,1),keyword3=c(0,0,1,0,0))
```

which is:

```
  names keyword1 keyword2 keyword3
1  artA        0        1        0
2  artA        1        1        0
3  artB        0        0        1
4  artC        1        1        0
5  artC        1        1        0
```

You can get it into a format using suitable for the above function by a suitable use of `aggregate`:

```
> df <- aggregate(. ~ names,data = df, max)
> row.names(df) <- as.character(df$names)
> df$names <- NULL
> df
     keyword1 keyword2 keyword3
artA        1        1        0
artB        1        1        1
artC        1        1        0
```

At this stage, `df` looks like your first table, and `as.matrix(df)` could be fed to the function `adj.matrix()`